# /page/2, /page/3, page redirects to main page permanlink error wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have an issue in WordPress, I am using a custom post. Pagination working perfectly in plain permalink setting but not working in custom structure /%postname%/  specially 2nd and 3rd results page.

example links not working
[www.website.com/page/2](http://www.website.com/page/2)
[www.website.com/page/3](http://www.website.com/page/3)

--search--
[www.website.com/page/2?s=searchkeyword](http://www.website.com/page/2?s=searchkeyword)
[www.website.com/page/3?s=searchkeyword](http://www.website.com/page/3?s=searchkeyword)

example links are working
[www.website.com/page/4](http://www.website.com/page/4) and onwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Pagination not working Page 2 same as Page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345744/wordpress-pagination-not-working-page-2-same-as-page-1)

Comment: No i need to keep page/ as a link for seo

Comment: That solution doesn't remove `page/`