# Pagination not Working on Wordpress. Posts doesn't change

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to configure the Wordpress pagination in de Index homepage.

I've used the WP_Query with the regard of get_query_var('paged') before, just as the code shows:

```
<?php
 $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
 $query = new WP_Query( array(
 'cat' => 7,
 'posts_per_page' => 2,
 'paged' => $paged
 ) );
?>
```

Then I used the native Wordpress function previous_posts_link() to go back onte the list of posts.

The problem that happens is that when the page loads, the url of the page changes, but the posts that shows are the same as before. Even to page 3 or 4, it just shows the same list of pages.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Pagination not working Page 2 same as Page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345744/wordpress-pagination-not-working-page-2-same-as-page-1)

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the help.